# how to make php expressions and execute from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that stores various type of operators and values that make expressions like

```
if(mydBVal1 mydBExpression mydBval2)
{
   // do something....!
}
```

Here is my code thats shows and example of what I want to say and the help I require
e.g:

```
$data['myValue'] = 100;
$data['operator'] = "<";
$data['comparison_value'] = 150

if( $data['myValue'] . $data['operator'] . $data['comparison_value'] )
{
    ///do something......
}
```

I want that if condition to be read as `if(100 < 150){}`, but the if condition expression is not working properly!

any one here know how I can make it work?

Comment: Given the limited set of comparison operators, it would probably be ok to just use a `switch` on the `$data['operator']` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the `eval()` function.

Be very careful about sanitising the data from the database before evaling it though as you could allow users to execute PHP code that you don't want them to.

```
$data['myValue']=100;
$data['operator']="<";
$data['comparison_value']= 150;

$eval = sprintf("return(%d %s %d);", $data['myValue'], $data['operator'], $data['comparison_value']);

if(eval($eval))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can take a look into php assert

[php.net/assert](http://php.net/assert)

```
<?php 

var_dump(assert("1 == 1"));
var_dump(assert("1 === null"));

?>
```

**Sample code I used related to my project:**

```
$assert_statement =
            (($typecriteria != 'IS_NULL' || $typecriteria != 'NOT_NULL' ) ? "'".$value."'" : '' )
            . " " .  $typecriteria . " '" . $criteriavalue."'";
            // Active assert and make it quiet
            assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1);
            assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING, 0);
            assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL, 0);
            assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 1);
            if ( $debug >= 1 ) {
                print __METHOD__." assert debug ".$assert_statement."<br>";
                var_dump(assert( $assert_statement ));
            }

            if (assert( $assert_statement ) === true )
            {
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: It's worth noting from the PHP documentation that: `Assertions should be used as a debugging feature only. You may use them for sanity-checks that test for conditions that should always be TRUE and that indicate some programming errors if not or to check for the presence of certain features like extension functions or certain system limits and features.`