# How can I store a PHP conditional staement in the database for later use?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

In our current application I have a report that contains something like:

```
if($foo == 3 || $bar > 3) {
    $e = someFunction();
};
```

but for a different client that same expression might be:

```
if($foo == 3 || $bar == 5 && $foobar != 9) {
    $e = someFunction();
};
```

Is there an straight-forward way to store the two different expressions, just the

```
$foo == 3 || $bar > 3 OR $foo == 3 || $bar == 5
```

bits in the database (MySQL) so I do not have to hard code all of these rules by client or maintain client versions of the same report.  I'm trying to figure out if I can set a variable o replace the conditions.  Something like:

```
$conditions = $row_rsConditions['condition_row']    //Get $foo == 3 || $bar > 3 from the DB and store it as $conditions
if($conditions) {
    $e = someFunction();
};
```

There could be > 100 different clients and each client could/would have a different set of expressions.
I'm just not sure of the right/best way to do this.

**UPDATE**:

I think I understand the issues using PHP's eval() function.  But because of the number of possible combinations I am leaning towards using the DB to store the conditions (not sure about using eval() just yet)

Does it make any difference (safer) if there is no user facing interface that writes to the condition field/table?  It could be something we manage on our end alone.

Comment: How about saving the code to database and later loading and executing using `eval`? Thoug there might be security issues when someone injects the database and makes you eval his code.

Comment: Then, the question is, for which circumstances, those operators inside conditions can change?

Comment: I think it's very bad design to store logic in database, database should be used only for data

Comment: Databases are for, well, data. Not for logic. You should probably leave that hard-coded into the script. There are very very few cases where you'll want to save code in your database. (The only example I can think of is a paste site such as http://codepad.com)

Comment: @Fivell: So how would you solve this? I consider it bad design too, to hardcode everything into a file.

Comment: @Jason I think you need to take it back to fundamentals. Can you make a data-structure for these conditions? Eg loop through a list? Can you make a bit-wise comparison on an integer maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would be very careful about storing logic in the database.

1. you code is no longer all in one place.
2. logic in the database is unlikely to be under source control
3. if you change the code and breaks all of that client specific logic, you have to go back into the database and edit it for every client.
4. other people could have access to the database and could change the code to something malicious.

this might not be the best solution
but i would suggest creating an abstract base class, then inherit from that, a class specific to each client.

Any functions that are customised can be added as a method to the base class, and overridden for client specific implementation.

use a switch statement to instantiate the class based on a client id or name (something that doesn't change) that you already store in the database.

```
switch ($client_name) {

case "abc ltd":
   $customlogic = new CustomLogicAbc();
   break;

case "zyx ltd":
   $customlogic = new CustomLogicXyz();
   break;

default: 
   $customlogic = new CustomLogicDefault();
   break;

}

if ($customlogic->doSomething($parm1, $parm2)) {
  // custom logic has been applied
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is relative simple, meaning he is only going to check those two values. But he has lots of different conditions on them that all would have to be coded. Instead parametrizing this would only require one implementation and fetching the conditions as he wants it.

Comment: So if there are 100+ clients this option still is feasible?  I'll agree with your #1 and #2 points.  #3 is on us to maintain properly and #4 - if they can change that then they can do a lot more damage already, right?

Comment: it really depends how much custom logic you have and how complex it is. if you only have that 1 statement shown in your example, then you may be better to store the $foo and $bar parameters in the database against each client record rather then the actual logic itself. If you have a lot of customised statements and they are complex, then i would do as i have done above, as the chances are the logic will only get more complex as you go, and you will add more customised stuff as well

Comment: Yeah, I'm concerned that not using the DB will lead to a huge file that needs maintained and parsed - but I'm concerned about the security around eval();

Comment: if the conditions need to be user editable, paramatise them and store the parameters in the database. if they will be maintained by you and it is just that one simple statement (like in your example), just go for 1 big switch/case statement with 100 options. no matter how you store it (db or script), you are still going to have to maintain and change it. is that easier done in 1 script file or by editing 100 database fields?

Comment: Good point on having to maintain regardless.  I wonder how slow a switch statement with 100 options is.  Right now I'm leaning this direction as eval() seems potentially unsafe.

Comment: the switch statement will be faster then a database call, i can tell you that much

Comment: @bumperbox Thanks for all your input - I'm going to go down the switch route.

Comment: What if the expressions are dynamic and keep on changing frequently and what if we need to provide a UI to the clients for adding/modifying/deleting their expressions?

Comment: @backslashN you are talking about client editable stuff, that is a different ball game. Depending on the complexity of your expressions, you could come up with some made up functions, maybe pinch some from excel SUM($x, $y). then translate those back to php. If you trust your clients to write php, then by all means storing it in the db, and using eval might be your only option.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on my comment:

Your last code is nearly what I meant:

```
$conditions = $row_rsConditions['condition_row'];    //Get "$foo == 3 || $bar > 3"
if(eval("return (" . $conditions . ");")) {
    $e = someFunction();
}
```

However I will warn you again to remember the risk of doing this.
When you use code from the database it is likely that errors are within.
At least some security check should be done on the data to avoid misuse.

Another option that is a bit more complicated but not that prone to misuse would be to encode the conditions. As it seems that you only compare 2 variables with a value each you could save for each variable something like:

```
0 !=
1 ==
2 >=
3 <=
4 >
5 <
```

To save the relation and additionally save the value to which it should be compared. That way there is no direct execution of code that is saved in the database.

Comment: @Gustav - Is it unsafe because I'd be opening up a place to allow for the injection of code or is there something more than that?

Comment: @Jason The PHP-injection part is the worst.

Answer (score 0):

nobody can tell you how to solve it because nobody knows functional requirements and specific logic of your application... But if time of implementation is important for you you can ofcourse try to use evaluationg of expressions from  database , but be careful and use sanitazing of all data from database... There is an example [how to make php expressions and execute from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936376/how-to-make-php-expressions-and-execute-from-database/5936398#5936398) - you just add more logic because you can have multiply conditions